# Keep a hidden textbox displayed after server side validation?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a slight issue here, on the form I have created. Firstly the user is presented with radio buttons. There are 3 radio button options Email, `MobileNo` and `AlternativePhoneNo`, however the confirm `MobileNo` and confirm `AlernativePhoneNo` text boxes only appears based on user selection of radio button.

The issue I have i.e. once user clicks on MobileNo, then the confirm MobileNo text box appears and when you type nothing in the confirm MobileNo text box and submit the form, it does the correct server side validation however the confirm MobileNo text box hides again and when you click the radio button MoibleNo again then the confirm text box appears validated how it should be.

I think I need to do `JQuery` or `JavaScript` function to always keep the hidden text box visible once user checks something above..???

Not sure how to do this this is my HTML.

```
<div id="ConfirmMobTelNo" class="confirmmobtelno col-md-6" style="display:none">
                <!--  <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo, "Confirm your mobile telephone no", new { @style = "", @class = "", id = "" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo, new { placeholder = "re-enter your mobile no here.", @style = "", @class = "form-control", id = "confirmmobtelno" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo)
            </div>
```

This is my Javascript

```
<script>

    $('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]').click(function () { //.communication class passed input name == model public communication
        if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNo") { //if value TelephoneNo selected in model
            $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
        } else {
            $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
        }

        if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNoAlternative") {  //if value == to TelephoneNoalternative
            $('.confirmalttelno').show(); //show confirm alt tel no text box
        } else {
            $('.confirmalttelno').hide(); //else hide it
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us your RadioButton html? Also your model?

Comment: And why are you not just doing client side validation to prevent the form being submitted?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to reload the page with the related hidden displayed based on the selected radio input, is that right?

If yes, you can *force* the click in order to show the related hidden on your radio input. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]:checked').click();
});
```

The above snippet calls the `click` event on the selected(`:checked`) radio box. It should work as if user have click it by itself.

Comment: That dont enable the hidden text boxes once i code it. I did this 
  $(function () {
            $('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]:checked').click();
       
     
            if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNo") { //if value TelephoneNo selected in model
                $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
            } else {
                $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
            }

Comment: @WaqarMalik the `.click()` method calls the event you already defined in your code, you don't need to do it all again. Put a `debugger;` inside your event and check if it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a on page load above my code such as below so this loads the first time.

```
    var checkedVal = $('.communicationCB input[name=CCommmunication]:checked').val(); //Added a variable to check the value
    if (checkedVal == "TelephoneNo") { //if checked valuie
        $('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
    } else {
        $('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
    };

    if (checkedVal == "TelephoneNoAlternative") {  //if checked valuie == to TelephoneNoalternative
        $('.confirmalttelno').show(); //show confirm alt tel no text box
    } else {
        $('.confirmalttelno').hide(); //else hide it
    };
```

Comment: It is the same code you have inside the click event. As I proposed, the `.click()` method should run that event, so the effect would be the same, and you won't need to replicate the same code twice in your page, what is not a good practice actually.